# The command for alias local='...' gets run on terminal open

Tags: terminal, mac, bash, mojave, alias

I have an alias set up in my .bash_profile file: `alias local='npm run start-local'`, and for whatever reason when I open a new terminal session it is trying to run that command  `npm run start-local` immediately. It works fine if I rename it to "local2". What could be causing this?

I got this alias from my coworker who uses it regularly, and the only difference I know of is that he is not on Mojave.

Edit: something interesting I noticed is that if I change it to `alias local='echo '` then I see

```
NVM_AUTO_MODE
NVM_CURRENT
NVM_MODE
VERSION
-bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Which adds evidence that it is running my local command when something is trying to  use the local variable.

Comment: Is  your coworker using as bash shell?

Comment: I tried adding a variety of `alias local` commands to my .bash_profile and I couldn't reproduce the behaviour you describe. It seems something specific to your machine is causing `local` to be invoked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not recreate what you have said is happening to you.

Saying that I would say that: **It is really very dangerous** to invoke `local` as your `alias`

Because the word `local` is a shell builtin, a reserved word for the default Bash shell to define a local variable in Bash script inside a Bash function. If you do `type local` from a new terminal window after removing it from your `alias` or by `unalias local` and then you would see it says:

```
local is a shell builtin
```

That is why, when you changed your `alias` to `local2` from `local` it worked fine since `local2` is not a shell builtin.

However, if you are using Korn Shell (version 93u+), `local` is not a shell builtin there. But, in most other shells `local` is a reserved word or shell builtin. So, in short: `local` should not be stored as an `alias`

For more information about shell builtin, look at man page: `man builtin`

Also, as mentioned by Gordon Davidson, there is definitely something calling the `local` variable and since you have overridden it as an alias for `npm`, it is running each time you are opening a new session.

Comment: I'll bet there's something in one of the shell startup scripts that tries to use `local` for its normal function (declaring a local shell variable), and because of the alias it's running `npm` instead. Not having the variable declared properly may prevent the script from working properly. This is why it's really dangerous to override standard commands unless you know exactly what you're doing.